# need to convert complex json obj to suitable angularjs ui tree data json structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

In  my angularjs project I have original json in the following format :

```
$scope.orgJsonObj = {  
  "parentNodesList":[  
    "0",
    "1",
    "1.1",
    "2",
    "2.2"
  ],
  "childNodes":{  
    "0":[  
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "1":[  
      "1.1",
      "1.2"
    ],
    "1.1":[  
      "1.1.1"
    ],
    "2":[  
      "2.1",
      "2.2"
    ],
    "2.2":[  
      "2.2.1",
      "2.2.3"
    ]
  },
  "nodeDetailsList":[  
    {  
      "id":"0",
      "name":"node0"
    },
    {  
      "id":"1",
      "name":"node1",
      "parentId":"0"
    },
    {  
      "id":"2",
      "name":"node2",
      "parentId":"0"
    },
    {  
      "id":"1.1",
      "name":"node1.1",
      "parentId":"1"
    },
    {  
      "id":"1.2",
      "name":"node1.2",
      "parentId":"1"
    },
    {  
      "id":"1.1.1",
      "name":"node1.1.1",
      "parentId":"1.1"
    },
    {  
      "id":"2.1",
      "name":"node2.1",
      "parentId":"2"
    },
    {  
      "id":"2.2",
      "name":"node2.2",
      "parentId":"2"
    },
    {  
      "id":"2.2.1",
      "name":"node2.2.1",
      "parentId":"2.2"
    },
    {  
      "id":"2.2.3",
      "name":"node2.2.3",
      "parentId":"2.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to convert `orgJsonObj` json structure in to the tree structure similar to [angular ui tree](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example)  json data structure. In `orgJsonObj`, `parentNodesList` contains all parents in the tree. Each parent's children list is available in  `childNodes`. Each nodes complete information is available in `nodeDetailsList`. The node obj `{ "id":"0", "name":"node0"}` does not have `parentId`, property in it because it is the root of the tree.

After conversion my `$scope.orgJsonObj`, should become as shown below (which is suitable for angularjs ui tree)

```
$scope.finalJsonObj = [  
  {  
    "id":"0",
    "title":"node0",
    "nodes":[  
      {  
        "id":"1",
        "title":"node1",
        "nodes":[  
          {  
            "id":"1.1",
            "title":"node1.1",
            "nodes":[  
              {  
                "id":"1.1.1",
                "title":"node1.1.1",
                "nodes":[  

                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {  
            "id":"1.2",
            "title":"node1.2",
            "nodes":[  

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {  
        "id":"2",
        "title":"node2",
        "nodes":[  
          {  
            "id":"2.1",
            "title":"node2.1",
            "nodes":[  

            ]
          },
          {  
            "id":"2.2",
            "title":"node2.2",
            "nodes":[  
              {  
                "id":"2.2.1",
                "title":"node2.2.1",
                "nodes":[  

                ]
              },
              {  
                "id":"2.2.3",
                "title":"node2.2.3",
                "nodes":[  

                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var originalData = {};

var treeData = transformNesting("0", originalData.childNodes);
var result = applyData(treeData, originalData.nodeDetailsList);

function transformNesting(root, nestedData){
    var tree = {
        id: root,
        nodes: nestedData[root] ? nestedData[root].map(function(newRoot){ return transformNesting(newRoot, nestedData)}) : []
    };
    return tree;
}

function getNodeById(list, id){
    return list.filter(function(item){
       return item.id === id;
    })[0];
}

function applyData(tree, config){
    tree.title = getNodeById(config, tree.id).name;
    tree.nodes =  tree.nodes.map(function(node){return applyData(node, config)});
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: hi @Valery Kozlov, do you have jsfiddle for this

Comment: i want to transform this data to tree `data = [{ "id": 1,"parent": 0,"name":"Parent"},  { "id": 2, "parent": 1,"name": "Child 1"}, {"id": 3, "parent": 2,"name": "Grand Child 1"}, { "id": 4, "parent": 2, "name": "Grand Child 2"}, {"id": 5,  "parent": 1,  "name": "Child 2"} ,{ "id": 11, "parent": 0, "name": "Parent"}, {  "id": 22,  "parent": 11,  "name": "Child 22 22"}, { "id": 33, "parent": 22, "name": "Grand Child 22 33"}, {"id": 44,
    "parent": 22,
    "name": "Grand Child 22 44"
  }, {
    "id": 55,
    "parent": 11,
    "name": "Child 22 55"
  }];`

Comment: is opposite task, have no time to code it right now, sry.

Comment: ok thank you i have already got the solution ,  check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910947/how-to-make-desired-json-tree-from-simple-json/48914207#48914207