# how to get construct object in specified manner from given object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have problem in constructing a `object` in desired format.

i want to get the object in this manner

```
{"pendrive":['went to each object and picked "TEST_HOME" value'],"minichip":['went to each object and picked "TEST_PROXY" value']}
```

the value of the above `array` must be collected from each `object` by going to `mount_status` then `key` , for **example** `TEST_PROXY`,`TEST_HOME`,`TEST_ARCHIVE`,`TEST_TARGET`

**Desired Output:** `{"pendrive":["error","na","error","ok","na","na"]}`   for key `"TEST_HOME"`  **AND same for others**

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
  var nodeSum = {};
var nodeStatus = {
  "node_stats": {
    "pendrive": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "error",
        "TEST_TARGET": "error",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error",
        "TEST_HOME": "error"
      }
    },
    "minichip": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_HOME": "na"
      }
    },
    "simcard": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "error",
        "TEST_TARGET": "error",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error",
        "TEST_PROXY": "error"
      }
    },
    "hostname": [
      "nikola",
      "goldplus",
      "pendrive",
      "simcard",
      "airtel",
      "minichip",
      "voda"
    ],
    "airtel": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "ok",
        "TEST_TARGET": "ok",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "ok",
        "TEST_HOME": "ok"
      }
    },
    "voda": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_PROXY": "na"
      }
    },
    "nikola": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_PROXY": "na"
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(nodeStatus);

var hostNames = nodeStatus["node_stats"]["hostname"];

for(var i = 0; i<hostNames.length;i++){

  if(nodeStatus["node_stats"][hostNames[i]]){
    eachNode = nodeStatus["node_stats"][hostNames[i]];
    console.log(eachNode);
  }
  //nodeSum[hostNames[i]] = eachNode["mount_status"][Object.keys(eachNode["mount_status"])];
  if(eachNode){
    if(eachNode.hasOwnProperty("mount_status")){
      if(i <= 1)
        var allBins = Object.keys(eachNode["mount_status"]);
        console.log('all keys',allBins);
        console.log(nodeStatus["node_stats"][hostNames[i]][allBins[i]]);
        console.log(Object.values(eachNode["mount_status"]));

        var binStatusArray = Object.values(eachNode["mount_status"]);
        nodeSum[allBins[i]] = eachNode["mount_status"][allBins[i]];
      }
    }         
  }
  console.log('results',nodeSum);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want do have `{"pendrive":["error","na","error","ok","na","na"]}` when only one `TEST_HOME` is its child, are you sure you don't want it for `node_stats`?

Comment: Your indentation makes this code very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object lookup for each type of item and property name. Then Using `Object.keys()` iterate through each key of lookup and `array#reduce` each key with all the values corresponding to lookup property and create an array using `array#reduce` of all the values of each object.

```js
var nodeStatus = { "node_stats": { "pendrive": { "mount_status": { "TEST_PROXY": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error", "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_HOME": "error" } }, "minichip": { "mount_status": { "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na", "TEST_ARCHIVE":"na", "TEST_HOME": "na" } }, "simcard": { "mount_status":{ "TEST_HOME": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error", "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_PROXY": "error" } }, "hostname": [ "nikola", "goldplus", "pendrive", "simcard", "airtel", "minichip", "voda" ], "airtel":{ "mount_status": { "TEST_PROXY": "ok", "TEST_TARGET": "ok", "TEST_ARCHIVE": "ok", "TEST_HOME": "ok" } }, "voda": { "mount_status": { "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na", "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na" } }, "nikola": { "mount_status": { "TEST_HOME":"na", "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na" } } } },
    lookup = {pendrive: 'TEST_HOME', minichip: 'TEST_PROXY'}
    result = Object.keys(lookup).reduce((o,k) => {
      o[k] =  Object.keys(nodeStatus.node_stats).reduce((r,key) => {
      if('mount_status' in nodeStatus.node_stats[key])
          r.push(nodeStatus.node_stats[key].mount_status[lookup[k]]);
      return r;
    },[]);
    return o;
   },{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible i would change the following

```
const nodeStatus = {
  "hostname": [
      "nikola",
      "goldplus",
      "pendrive",
      "simcard",
      "airtel",
      "minichip",
      "voda"
  ],
  "node_stats": {
    "pendrive": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "error",
        "TEST_TARGET": "error",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error",
        "TEST_HOME": "error"
      }
    },
    "minichip": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_HOME": "na"
      }
    },
    "simcard": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "error",
        "TEST_TARGET": "error",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "error",
        "TEST_PROXY": "error"
      }
    },
    "airtel": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_PROXY": "ok",
        "TEST_TARGET": "ok",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "ok",
        "TEST_HOME": "ok"
      }
    },
    "voda": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_PROXY": "na"
      }
    },
    "nikola": {
      "mount_status": {
        "TEST_HOME": "na",
        "TEST_ARCHIVE": "na",
        "TEST_TARGET": "na",
        "TEST_PROXY": "na"
      }
    }
  }
}

const testHome = nodeStatus.hostname.map(name => nodeStatus["node_stats"][name] 
  ? nodeStatus["node_stats"][name]["mount_status"]["TEST_HOME"] 
  : undefined);

// ["nikola", "goldplus", "pendrive", "simcard", "airtel", "minichip", "voda"]
console.log(testHome) //["na", undefined, "error", "error", "ok", "na", "na"]
```

hostname differs from all others, so you want to get it out of `node_stats`. The order of the result will be the same as the order of `hostname`

If you don't want the undefined, then you can use `Array.reduce`, but the side effect would be that the order of the `Array` would be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

### If you want output like this:

for key of `TEST_ARCHIVE`

```
{error: ["pendrive", "simcard"], na: ["minichip", "voda", "nikola"], ok: ["airtel"]}
```

### Use this:

```js
function getNestedValuesForKey(key_name){
 var hosts = nodeStatus.node_stats;
 var return_values = {};
 for( var _hostname in hosts ){
  var _host = hosts[_hostname];
  if( _host.mount_status ){
   var _status = _host.mount_status[key_name];
   if( !return_values[_status] ){
    return_values[_status] = new Array;
   }//if
   return_values[_status].push(_hostname);
  }//if
 }//for
 return return_values
}//function

var nodeStatus = {"node_stats":{"pendrive":{"mount_status":{"TEST_PROXY":"error","TEST_TARGET":"error","TEST_ARCHIVE":"error","TEST_HOME":"error"}},"minichip":{"mount_status":{"TEST_PROXY":"na","TEST_TARGET":"na","TEST_ARCHIVE":"na","TEST_HOME":"na"}},"simcard":{"mount_status":{"TEST_HOME":"error","TEST_TARGET":"error","TEST_ARCHIVE":"error","TEST_PROXY":"error"}},"hostname":["nikola","goldplus","pendrive","simcard","airtel","minichip","voda"],"airtel":{"mount_status":{"TEST_PROXY":"ok","TEST_TARGET":"ok","TEST_ARCHIVE":"ok","TEST_HOME":"ok"}},"voda":{"mount_status":{"TEST_HOME":"na","TEST_TARGET":"na","TEST_ARCHIVE":"na","TEST_PROXY":"na"}},"nikola":{"mount_status":{"TEST_HOME":"na","TEST_ARCHIVE":"na","TEST_TARGET":"na","TEST_PROXY":"na"}}}};

console.log( getNestedValuesForKey('TEST_ARCHIVE') );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly unclear what you want.  One possibility is that when you're looking for `TEST_PROXY`, you should get

```
["na", undefined, "error", "error", "ok", "na", "na"]
```

(The `undefined` is because `hostname` includes "goldplus", which is not included in `node_stats`.)

If that's what you want, then this should work:

```js
const nodeStatus = {"node_stats": {"airtel": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "ok", "TEST_HOME": "ok", "TEST_PROXY": "ok", "TEST_TARGET": "ok"}}, "hostname": ["nikola", "goldplus", "pendrive", "simcard", "airtel", "minichip", "voda"], "minichip": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}, "nikola": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}, "pendrive": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_HOME": "error", "TEST_PROXY": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error"}}, "simcard": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_HOME": "error", "TEST_PROXY": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error"}}, "voda": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}}}

const nodeSum = (key, nodes) => nodes.node_stats.hostname
    .map(hostname => (nodes.node_stats[hostname] || {mount_status: {}}).mount_status[key])


console.log(nodeSum("TEST_PROXY", nodeStatus))
```

But that's format is fairly unclear.  If instead you would like something like this:

```
{
  "nikola":"na",
  "pendrive":"error",
  "simcard":"error",
  "airtel":"ok",
  "minichip":"na",
  "voda":"na"
}
```

Then you could modify the function a bit like this:

```js
const nodeStatus = {"node_stats": {"airtel": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "ok", "TEST_HOME": "ok", "TEST_PROXY": "ok", "TEST_TARGET": "ok"}}, "hostname": ["nikola", "goldplus", "pendrive", "simcard", "airtel", "minichip", "voda"], "minichip": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}, "nikola": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}, "pendrive": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_HOME": "error", "TEST_PROXY": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error"}}, "simcard": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "error", "TEST_HOME": "error", "TEST_PROXY": "error", "TEST_TARGET": "error"}}, "voda": {"mount_status": {"TEST_ARCHIVE": "na", "TEST_HOME": "na", "TEST_PROXY": "na", "TEST_TARGET": "na"}}}}

const nodeSum = (key, nodes) => nodes.node_stats.hostname
    .map(hostname => ({[hostname]: (nodes.node_stats[hostname] || {mount_status: {}})
                                   .mount_status[key]}))
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})

console.log(nodeSum("TEST_HOME", nodeStatus))
```

If you could guarantee that there were no scenarios like "goldplus" in your example where a hostname is included in the lists of hostnames but not in `node_stats`, then you could simplify these functions to

```
const nodeSum = (key, nodes) => nodes.node_stats.hostname
    .map(hostname => nodes.node_stats[hostname].mount_status[key])
```

and

```
const nodeSum = (key, nodes) => nodes.node_stats.hostname
    .map(hostname => ({[hostname]: nodes.node_stats[hostname].mount_status[key]}))
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a, b), {})
```

And finally, it might be cleaner to do the latter in a single iteration, like this:

```
const nodeSum = (key, nodes) => nodes.node_stats.hostname
    .reduce((acc, hostname) => {
      acc[hostname] = nodes.node_stats[hostname].mount_status[key]
      return acc
    }, {})
```

---

`nodeSum` is a *terrible* name for this function, but it seemed that you were updating a variable with this name to hold your output.  I would change it to something more explicit for real code.